# Find a value in a column and output a variable from the same row in Matlab

Tags: matlab, indexing, full-text-search

Find a value in a column and output a variable from the same row.

I have a dataset in Matlab which looks like this:

```
423  2433  443
424  4333  233
425  3422  334
426  3241  213 
427  2342  234
```

I need to make it such that if I use "425", and search for the corresponding values in the row that has "425"... the code would pull 3422 and 334 respectively.

What code should I use to do this in Matlab?

Help would be appreciated,

Sincerely

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy with [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/):

```
data = [
423  2433  443
424  4333  233
425  3422  334
426  3241  213 
427  2342  234 ];

result = data(data(:,1)==425,2:end)
```

gives you a vector with the two desired numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
result = data(data(:,1)==425,2:end)
```

Comment: The other answer does not work if the second or third column also contain 425